What are the rules/regulations/laws regarding bringing nicotine pouches for personal use when traveling to Japan by air?
I will be traveling from the US to Japan in a couple weeks for vacation.  I am a nicotine user and usually prefer to use disposable vapes.  However, I know that the laws/regulations forbid the possession/use of any liquids containing nicotine and will not be bringing or planning to purchase any of those vapes.
I was hoping that I would be able to supplement with nicotine pouches, Zyns preferably, and wanted to know what the rules were on this.
Am I able to purchase these Zyns in the US (for personal use so probably only 2-3 tins) and bring them with me on the plane (carry on), through customs, and into the country?
Are there limits are the strength? Zyn offers at least 3mg and 6mg.
Any related information or similar cases would be helpful! I tried to search for this case specifically but mainly just found information on the nicotine liquid.  Thank you!

Good news! You actually can legally import up to 120 ml of vape liquid, even if it contains nicotine, into Japan. JNTO:

Can I bring my e-cigarette and vape liquid?
Electronic cigarette cartridges and liquids that contain nicotine are
classified as medicinal products and are regulated under the Japanese
pharmaceutical affairs law.
If you wish to bring them into Japan, the amount that can be cleared
by the customs is up to 120 ml (liquid) for a one-month dosage. If you
wish to import cartridges or liquids beyond this amount, it is
necessary to obtain a medicine supervision certificate before travel.

However, there is one catch: only two "devices" are permitted, presumably including disposable vapes.

Electronic cigarette cartridges and devices for atomizing liquids are
also regarded as medical devices. When importing these, only one
device (or two if a spare one is required) can be cleared through
customs clearance.

Regarding ZYN, I'm not sure if legislation has evolved far enough to cover this, but generally tobacco replacement products with nicotine (gum etc) are widely available and can be imported for personal use, so this should be fine too.

Thank you very much for all the great info! I have a couple of clarifications.  One, based on what you said if i bring below 120ml of vape liquid, I require no medical clearance and can simply toss it in my bag?  Second, do you happen to know where disposable vapes fall? This would be the rechargable but not refillable kind.  Where when it is out its out.  I believe, but am not certain that they are cotton soaked in vape liquid that is then vaporized.  Thanks again!


Yes 2) The rules don't differentiate, the limit is two "devices" period.


Great, thanks again! I really appreciate your help.
